# contar filas en la base de datos y comparar el resultado laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

necesito contar cuantos tipos de registros tienen un valor predeterminado, en mi caso estoy contando las filas donde el estado_pedido sea 3

este es mi código en el controlador:

```js
$disponibilidad = \DB::table('pedidos')
        ->select(\DB::raw('count(*) estado_pedidos'))
        ->where('estado_pedidos', '=', 3)
        ->get();
 return $disponibilidad;
```

me funciona, me da el resultado que espero pero luego necesito compararlo, es aquí donde tengo el problema pues  disponibilidad me devuelve un array con un objeto dentro y necesito la cantidad (disponibilidad que a su vez es la que almacena el count) en integer, para poder compararla.
este es mi resultado que me devuelve la consulta anterior:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o lo otro seria poder acceder a lo que me devuelve y rescatar el valor, pero eh intentado varias formas pero no lo eh logrado, como podría obtener el resultado dentro del objeto y convertirlo para su posterior comparación?

en resumidas cuentas solo necesito saber si me trae alguna fila donde el estado_pedido de la tabla tenga estado 3, si me trae algo que me muestre un mensaje "si tiene" y si no hay campos con estado 3 un mensaje "no tiene"
pero solo el tema de la comparación me complica ya que me devuelve un objeto.
estoy usando laravel 5.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza el método count al momento de hacer la consulta con el Query Builder:

```
$disponibilidad = \DB::table('pedidos')
    ->whereEstadoPedidos(3)
    ->count();
```

Esta consulta debería entregar el valor correspondiente, sin arrays ni colecciones.

Comment: muchas gracias :)

Comment: bueno tuve que agregar lo siguiente ya que si no habian registro el valor era null, la razon? no habia nada que contar con lo siguiente lo solucione:    
         return  $retVal = (($disponibilidad == 0) || ($disponibilidad == null)) ? "disponible" : "no disponible" ;

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo estás haciendo con js, no? En ese caso, si tu variable $disponibilidad se la has asignado a una variable en js "disponibilidad", puedes acceder al valor de la propiedad así:

```
var numero = disponibilidad[0]['estado_pedidos'];
console.log(numero);
```

---

En caso de querer obtener el valor en PHP sería:

```
$numero = $disponibilidad[0]->estado_pedidos;
```

Aunque puedes utilizar otras formas más sencillas. Por ejemplo, directamente con Eloquent puedes hacer:

En el caso de que tengas un modelo de Pedidos, el ORM, etc, ...podrías hacer esto:

```
$disponibilidad = Pedidos::where('estado_pedidos',3)->count();
```

Sino también puedes utilizar el método first() y acceder directamente a la propiedad. Al fin y al cabo sabes que esa consulta siempre te va a devolver solo una linea.

```
$disponibilidad = \DB::table('pedidos')
        ->select(\DB::raw('count(*) estado_pedidos'))
        ->where('estado_pedidos', '=', 3)
        ->first()->estado_pedidos;
```

Comment: es php, uso laravel como framework

Comment: Lo se. Perdona, pensé que estabas sacando el resultado en un console.log(). Edito mi respuesta.